# What is the relationship between rig and armature?

Tags: rigging, armature

I'm a beginner to rigging characters and I don't understand what the relationship between the armature and the rig is. I parent my body mesh to both the armature bones and the generated rig, but when I use the rig, the bones don't follow.

I'm having trouble understanding how to use both. For example, if I have a generated rig, what do i do with the bones? Are they supposed to be parented with each other?

Comment: if you use Rigify for example, you don't need the original armature anymore, you just need to parent to the new armature, its deforming bones are invisible (you can make their layer visible if needed), only the controlling bones are visible

Comment: @moonboots hi thanks for the quick response, where would you be able to make deforming bones visible?

Comment: it depends on your Blender version, in Blender 4 it's a new system of layers, go into the Data panel > Bone Collections: https://zupimages.net/up/24/04/w5gj.jpg